# useEffect when onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting stuck about how to use effects together with app logic.

Suppose this component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect( () => {
    fetch('https://www.google.com?q='+query)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
  }); // depends on what?

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} value={query} />
      <button>Ask Google about {query}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want that:

- when (and only) the user clicks the button the fetch is run with the correct query value of the input
- if the fetch is still in progress and the user clicks, the fetch is skipped but the effect is fired (meaning: I intentionally not disable the button, I want that the effect function is run, but I put a check inside that function not to execute the fetch).

Problems:

- The effect shouldn't fire on mount (it wouldn't make any sense)
- The effect shouldn't fire when the query changes, but if I don't put the query variable inside the useEffect dependency array, React complains (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
- The effect should fire when the user click on the button; I achieved this for example using a fake state `isRun`, setting `onClick={setIsRun(true)}`, making the effect depending on `[isRun]`, setting `setIsRun(false)` at the end of the effect function, and checking `if (!isRun)` at the beginning of the effect function to prevent that when is set to false from the effect itself it is run again since the state changes. This works, but I find it very verbose and uncomfortable...
- The effect should fire if the button is clicked again (with the same `query` value or not) and the previous fetch has not yet finished without running the fetch: with the previous solution with `isRun` it wouldn't fire because `isRun` is already set to `1` so there is no state change; maybe with another state there is a way, but again very verbose and counterintuitive.
- Most importantly: the code should be clean and readable without using "tricks"!

How would you write such a component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you shouldn't be using `useEffect` for this at all.  You want this to happen on a user action, not as an effect:

> when (and only) the user clicks the button the fetch is run with the correct query value of the input

Remove `useEffect` and create a function to handle the click:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    fetch('https://www.google.com?q='+e.target.value)
        .then(response => console.log(response));
};
```

And pass that function to the component:

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>Ask Google about {query}</button>
```

What seems confusing here are these requirements:

> - if the fetch is still in progress and the user clicks, the fetch is skipped but the effect is fired
> - The effect should fire if the button is clicked again (with the same query value or not) and the previous fetch has not yet finished without running the fetch

The only thing the function does is execute a `fetch`.  So should that operation happen or not?  Your proposed solution of keeping state in a variable (`isRun`) to determine if it should happen or not should work in this case.  I think the problem before was mixing that up with `useEffect` when all you really want is a function.  Add `isRun` to state and update it accordingly when performing the operation:

```
const [isRun, setIsRun] = useState(false);

const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (isRun) { return; }
    setIsRun(true);
    fetch('https://www.google.com?q='+e.target.value)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            setIsRun(false);
        });
};
```

Comment: I understand, now I'm more confused than before :-) Wasn't a core React rule that everything which deals with state and props in asynchronous way should be put in an effect otherwise you aren't guaranteed that the data will be read/written as intended? I used an effect in the example since I'm reading the state (query), and I might as well set the state after the fetch maybe to pass the result to another component as a prop. Isn't that the use case for useEffect?

Comment: @edoedoedo: `useEffect` is meant to perform an operation (a "side effect") when mounting a component, conditionally based on changes in a supplied dependency array.  But if you don't want this to happen when the component mounts, and want it to happen when the user clicks the button, then `useEffect` is the wrong tool for the job.  Handling `onClick` is how you perform an action in response to a user click.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I realize I completely misunderstood what effects are for. So for the classic use case where I retrieve some data when the user does something and then display these data in the component render, it is perfectly safe to use just function without the need of using effects, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to insist on using `useEffect` but it does not seem appropriate for this situation. What I could do is call a function on button click.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const handleQuery = (query) => {
    fetch('https://www.google.com?q='+query)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} value={query} />
      <button onClick={() => handleQuery(query)}>Ask Google about {query}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need to pass query to the function because you can just get it from the state